# Power of a controlled voltage source

Tags: voltage, power, control

I'm learning a bit about controlled sources and I'm a bit confused about calculating their power.
I have this circuit.
[image: schematic]
[Link to Falstad Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxGzxCQBZtqBTAWjDACgA3cQyCyG7rzDEUUMTV5Je06AjYAnQeBEgUCQstFDIbFGAHYEo4aJp4hK3qJQAqAIYKKRvgecoUA7WwDmS3ALAeJy0oNgB3VXVNYOidCMDefxikuJiTNJpPcIyBTKp9LIi88EyQYvSdRWL3XLMXMTBU4qTDURS2AA9kawRyMGwIIl4BD2oANU6yjCQ9Kl6RvTLVATsAGwAHAAs7AB0AZx2AR32UNiA)

According to the formula for power P = U * I, I get

- PR1 = 1.033W
- PR2 = 0.318W
- PR3 = 0.204W
- PRSum = 1.555W

The voltage source is outputting

- Psource = -1.607 W

The controlled voltage source output / takes?

- Pcv = (+/-)0.051W?

Normally the the sum of all powers equals to 0

But if I assume the controlled voltage source as a power "provider" it just doesn't add up.

So the controlled voltage source has to be a power sink just like a resistor?

Is this assumption right? If yes why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible for an ideal voltage source or an ideal current source to **consume** power in a circuit.

It's very important that you understand what these ideal sources do. You should think of them as **constraining** a voltage or current to have a certain value. If you think of them as creating voltage or current, or limiting voltage or current, then you will get confused in situations like this.

For a simple example, suppose we are charging a battery from a bench power supply. If we drew a rough schematic, both of these would be modeled as ideal voltage sources, even though the battery is **consuming** power. The battery **constrains** the voltage at its terminals to be some value because of the particular chemical reactions going on inside of it.